# How is Sefer Yeshayahu structured?

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

How is Sefer Yeshaya structured?  It doesn't seem to be chronological.  The book seems to start with chapter 6 which presumably took place during the reign of Uzziah.  Rashi says chapter 1 started after the Northern Kingdom was destroyed.

Comment: ...as the Malbim says in his introduction: ואין מוקדם ומאוחר בסדר הספר http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01887.html

Answer (score 1):

One structure I saw from a teacher of Tanach is as follows:

In terms of general structure:

Perakim 1-39 are rebuke.

Perakim 40-66 are comfort.

One can then look at the details of the first half of prophecies:

Perakim 1 and 11 are actually not rebuke, and are about the end of days. Therefore, the Malbim proposes:

1. If you do not repent, you will have problems
2. **Look how great it can be if you repent!** (Perek 2)
3. The downfall of the North followed by Assyria moving into the South = big problems and destruction.
4. **It's a lost cause, so discuss the furture again rather than rebuke.** (Perek 11)

The Malbim further mentions that a discussion of the end of days and "utopia" is only relevant when bnei yisrael are in trouble.

Lastly, I vaguely remember that Perek 2 is about the end of days that could have come right then if we were good, ie it's an actual option if we repent. However Perek 11 is now only a glimpse of what is destined to come at some point, but not an immediate choice.

Comment: More like 1-35. 36-39 are straight history/story.